# rowCount WHERE AND OR with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the number of conversations between two members.
When user 1 visits the profile of user 2, I have a visible result. But when user 2 visits profile 1, I have no result.

```
public function getNumberConversations($sender, $receiver) {

    $st = Database::getDatabase()->prepare("SELECT id, sender, receiver
        FROM conversation
        WHERE sender = ? AND receiver = ?
        OR receiver = ? AND sender = ?
    ");

    $st->execute(array($sender, $receiver, $receiver, $sender));

    return $st->rowCount();

  }
```

Comment: `WHERE (sender = ? AND receiver = ?)
        OR (receiver = ? AND sender = ?)`

Comment: Also, you are swapping the sender and the receiver twice: in the query and in the array. Net result: no swapping at all, and duplicated clause `WHERE (sender = $sender AND receiver = $receiver) OR (receiver = $receiver AND sender = $sender)`

Comment: I think brackets in this case are not the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change

```
$st->execute(array($sender, $receiver, $receiver, $sender));
```

with

```
$st->execute(array($sender, $receiver, $sender, $receiver));
```

In your case brackets are OK (AND precedence)

Answer (score 2):

use braces for condition

```
public function getNumberConversations($sender, $receiver) {

    $st = Database::getDatabase()->prepare("SELECT id, sender, receiver
        FROM conversation
        WHERE (sender = ? AND receiver = ?)
        OR (receiver = ? AND sender = ?)
    ");

    $st->execute(array($sender, $receiver, $sender, $receiver)); // also notice this

    return $st->rowCount();

  }
```

Comment: then update it in your question, otherwise everyone would have same answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to ad brackets for separating condition. Also you are swapping condition on both so it will become same. try following answer:

```
public function getNumberConversations($sender, $receiver) {

    $st = Database::getDatabase()->prepare("SELECT id, sender, receiver
        FROM conversation
        WHERE (sender = ? AND receiver = ?)
        OR (receiver = ? AND sender = ?)
    ");

    $st->execute(array($sender, $receiver, $sender, $receiver)); //<----change here also

    return $st->rowCount();

  }
```